# Why does failure of boundedness of this operator for $p<q$ implies its failure for $p>q^{\prime}$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, oscillatory-integral

I am reading the paper  "P.Sjolin, Convolution with Oscillating Kernels, Indiana University Mathematics Journal Vol. 30, No. 1 (1981), pp. 47-55" where $L^p-L^p$ boundedness of the operator
$$Tf(x)=\int \frac{e^{i|x-y|^{a}}}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}
  f(y)dy$$
is studied. Here $0<\alpha<n$ and $a>0$, $a\neq 1$.

The author repeatedly utilizes the claim that:

if the inequality
$$\|Tf\|_{p}\leq C \|f\|_{p}\qquad (1)$$
necessitates that $p\geq p_{0}$ for some $1< p_{0}\leq 2$ then (1) also necessitates that $p\leq p_{0}^{\prime}$, the dual exponent of $p_{0}$. That is if (1) is false for all $p<p_{0}$  for some $1<p_{0}\leq 2$
then (1) is also false for all $p>p_{0}^{\prime}$.

This seems to have something to do with duality but I can't make that precise. Where does this statement come from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard property of self-adjoint (including convolution) operators, following from duality.

Let $Tf = k*f$ and assume that $||Tf||_{p} \leq C ||f||_{p}$.

Then $$||Tf||_{p'} = \sup_{\substack{g \in L^p \\ ||g||_{p}} =1} \left<Tf,g\right> =\sup_{\substack{g \in L^p \\ ||g||_{p}} =1} \left<f,Tg\right>.$$
From Holder we then have that this is
$$\leq  \sup_{\substack{g \in L^p \\ ||g||_{p}} =1} ||Tg||_{p} ||f||_{p'} \leq C ||f||_{p'}.$$